# File Indexer Implementation

Tags: .net, indexing

My .NET application needs to access specific file types without searching the entire system. So, I would like to implement a file indexer so that I can access the list of files of a particular type easily. Which is the most optimal way to save the file details for faster searching based on file types.

Is there any free library available for indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) , [Indexing and searching source code with Lucene.Net](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/simoneb/archive/2007/06/29/Indexing-and-searching-source-code-with-Lucene.Net.aspx)